# How to add values above each bar in countplot in Seaborn in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have code to generate countplot in Python like below:

```
def plot_countplot_nominal(zmienna):
    """
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
    sns.countplot(data[f"{zmienna}"], order = data[f"{zmienna}"].value_counts().index)
    plt.title("Liczbeność poziomów zmiennej {}".format(zmienna) ,fontsize=13)
    plt.xlabel(f"{zmienna}",fontsize=13)
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

This code generate plot like below for categorical variable:

[image]

How can I modify my code in Python so as to have values above each bar like below ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ax.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load sample
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", data=titanic)

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I have error like below: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'bar_label'

Comment: What is your version of matplotlib? Here 3.4.3.

Comment: 3.3.4 is my version of matplotlib

Comment: You need a version >= [3.4.0](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.0/users/whats_new.html#new-automatic-labeling-for-bar-charts). Is it possible for you?

Comment: Ok, I upgraded it and it works :)

Comment: Corralien, how can I increase or decrease font of this description ?

Comment: Using `fontsize=10` and all available parameters for [`Text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)